# Windows 7 Export Power Plan Settings

Tags: windows-7, power

How can I export my custom `Power Plan Settings` in `Windows 7`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the start button and type `cmd` now right click on `cmd` and choose **Run as Administrator** or press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now type the following command in the command line windows

> powercfg list

[image]

type the command below for the power plan that you want to export, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

> Powercfg –export “C:\powerplan_name.pow” GUID

GUID=code like for

> Balanced.pow 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
>
> High Performance.pow 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
>
> Power Saver.pow a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
>
> custom.pow ***************

could be different

Change the **powerplan_name** with the power plan you want to import and you are done. This will save the **Powerplan.POW** file n your *C:* drive.

Now if you want to import the backed up power plan just run the command line with admin privileges and typr the following command

> Powercfg –Import “C:\Powerplan.pow”

Comment: I made a `.bat` file that exports the `Balanced` and `Power saver` power schemes and when I ran it, it imported another different power scheme with the same name, so I now have two `Balanced` and two `Power saver` schemes, how can I delete them before importing the new schemes, knowing that the `-delete` option needs the `GUID`?

Comment: @RevoltEr you can ask that as a separate question if [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16206/how-to-delete-built-in-windows-7-power-plans-and-why-you-probably-shouldnt/) doesn't help you. Hope it will help you.